# How to parse the string formate to another formate

Tags: ios, swift, date

How to parse date formate for following string

createdAt = "2021-09-03T19:33:44.791822+05:30" // from server end got value

```
      self.dateFormaterString(inputDate: "2021-09-03T19:33:44.791822+05:30")

      func dateFormaterString(inputDate: String) ->String{

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
 //       formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateStyle = .short
        if let date = formatter.date(from: inputDate){
            print(date)
        }
        return ""
    }
```

The following method dateFormaterString return nil breaking date value
How to convert **"2021-09-03T19:33:44.791822+05:30"** into **"09/07/2021"**

Comment: `InputString --(DateFormatterWithFormatCorrespondingToInputString)--> Date --(DateFormatterWithFormatCorrespondingToOutputString)--> OutputString`, that's the logic. Did you set the correct format of InputString (here `"2021-09-03T19:33:44.791822+05:30"`) for `formatter.format` in order to call with success `.date(from:)`? Answer is no. That's the first step. Then, we'll check afterwards how to get `"09/07/2021"` from `date`, but that's the second step.

Comment: For the `InputString` to `Date`, this should do the trick: `formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSZ"`. Then, I'll let you see yourself how to get  `"09/07/2021"` See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns for more infos on what means each character

Comment: @Larme thank you, I forgot to convert string to date and that to my required formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set initially input dateformat  `formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSZ"`

```
       func dateFormaterString(inputDate: String) ->String{
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSZ"
       
        guard let getDate = formatter.date(from: inputDate) else { return ""}
            
            formatter.dateStyle = .short 
           // if you want a exact op as 09/03/2021 then use 
           // formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
           return formatter.string(from: getDate)
        
    }
```

sample useage

```
   let value =  self.dateFormaterString(inputDate: "2021-09-03T19:33:44.791822+05:30")
    print(value)
```

you get the output as : 9/3/21